# Memoized objects still have their __init__() invoked?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5, memoization

So I am creating a memoized class, and have been observing a strange behavior.

Here's the snippet of the code:

```py
class SomeClass(object):

    _Memoized = {}

    def __new__(cls, id: str, *args, **kwargs):
        if id not in cls._Memoized:
            print('New Instance')
            cls._Memoized[id] = super(SomeClass, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print('Existing Instance')
        return cls._Memoized[id]

    def __init__(self, id: str):
        print('Running init')
        self.id = id


def test():
    w1 = SomeClass(id='w1')
    wx = SomeClass(id='w1')
    print(id(w1), id(wx), id(w1) == id(wx))

test()
```

Running the above code results in:

```
New Instance
Running init
Existing Instance
Running init   <===-------------------???
140008534476784 140008534476784 True
```

My questions: During the second invocation of `SomeClass()`, why does it execute the `__init__` constructor? Wasn't the `__init__` constructor only invoked on instantiating? Is there a way to prevent the `__init__` from being invoked?

Comment: When you define `__new__`, you usually do all the initialization work in `__new__`; just don't define `__init__` at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of `__new__` is to create a new instance, which is why Python calls `__init__` on it. You might instead override `__call__` on a metaclass to avoid creating a new instance.

```
class MemoMeta(type):
    def __init__(self, name, bases, namespace):
        super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)
        self.cache = {}
    def __call__(self, id_, *args, **kwargs):
        if id_ not in self.cache:
            print('New Instance')
            self.cache[id_] = super().__call__(id_, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print('Existing Instance')
        return self.cache[id_]

class SomeClass(metaclass=MemoMeta):
    def __init__(self, id_, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Running init')
        self.id = id_


def test():
    w1 = SomeClass(id_='w1')
    wx = SomeClass(id_='w1')
    print(id(w1), id(wx), id(w1) == id(wx))

test()
```

Comment: Well, except that by intercepting calls to `__new__` I actually prevented creation of new instances; notice the identical values for `id(w1)` and `id(wx)`. Your usage of a metaclass, however, is _very_ interesting and worth studying. Thanks for the advise!

Comment: Whoops tried your code as-is, and ended up with 2 different instances of SomeClass; last line is: `10739744 140559844255336 False`

Comment: Forgot a return