# How to not return object reference from __init__

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-item

I'm new to ItemLoaders.
I've a set `seen_ids` in which I add all the `product_ids` which I scrape so that I can check if there is any duplicate and skip it at earliest.

The problem is, I want to do this in `__init__`. If it's a duplicate, I don't want any reference to be returned, and I can't explicitly return None from `__init__`. How would I do that?

```
seen_ids = set()

def __init__(self, item=None, selector=None, response=None, parent=None, product_id=None, **context):
    if product_id in self.seen_ids:
        return None

    self.seen_ids.add(product_id)
    super(GarmentLoader, self).__init__(item, selector, response, parent, **context)
    item['retailer_sku'] = product_id
```

But it's giving error on None, and if I don't return anything, it returns object's reference and further checks fail.

Comment: This is not something you should handle at the `__init__` level, but at the `__new__` level.

Comment: Furthermore the value of the `__init__` does not matter, most `__init__`s in python do not return anything

Comment: Specifically, `__init__` takes the value returned by `__new__` and apply whatever instructions specified in `__init__` to that; any values returned by `__init__` are discarded.

Comment: will the instance creation will be same ??
`garment_loader = GarmentLoader(item=Garment(), response=response, product_id=product_id)` like this ??
how will I access product_id in __new__ ??

Comment: Also, the only way a construction of object can _not_ return an object is if it throws an error. I would be extremely surprised if `Foo()` returned `None`. Tentatively possible not-quite-duplicate-but-useful-nonetheless: [Memoized objects still have their __init__() invoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47785795/memoized-objects-still-have-their-init-invoked)

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't work because constructor basically doesn't return anything else than instance and because instances wouldn't share seen_ids.

You can use class method instead:

```
class CustomItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    seen_ids = set()

    @classmethod
    def with_product_id(cls, **kwargs):
        product_id = kwargs.pop('product_id', None)
        if product_id in cls.seen_ids:
            return None
        cls.seen_ids.add(product_id)
        return cls(**kwargs)
```

Then create loader's instance using it:

```
loader = CustomItemLoader.with_product_id(response=response, product_id=product_id, ...)
```